# Misterious USB dongle

Tags: hardware, usb, dongle

I have this USB stick that seems to have a slot for a SIM and for a SD card. I don't know nothing else about this module. Searching the codes on internet I didn't find anything.

[image: One side]
[image: The other side]

How could I find something out about this? And maybe use it in some way?

EDIT:
It is recognized by the operative system (lsusb output `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0b3c:c003 Olivetti Techcenter`)

And the kernel logs are:

```
[ 5956.949288] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 5956.981766] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b3c, idProduct=f000, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 5956.981773] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 5956.981778] usb 1-1.2: Product: HSPA Data Card
[ 5956.981781] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: USBModem
[ 5956.981785] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDEF
[ 5956.984482] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5956.984793] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 5958.011311] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5958.012120] scsi 4:0:0:1: CD-ROM            USBModem MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5958.013018] scsi 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5958.018397] sr 4:0:0:1: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[ 5958.019526] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5958.020236] sr 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 5958.020807] sr 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[ 5958.323118] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 5958.545345] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 5958.577667] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b3c, idProduct=c003, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 5958.577674] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 5958.577678] usb 1-1.2: Product: HSPA Data Card
[ 5958.577682] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: USBModem
[ 5958.577685] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDEF
[ 5958.580800] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5958.581066] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 5958.581601] option 1-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5958.582001] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 5958.582423] option 1-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5958.582890] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 5958.583337] option 1-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5958.583616] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[ 5958.583812] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5958.586890] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.4
[ 5958.587195] option 1-1.2:1.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 5958.587354] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[ 5959.610911] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5959.611878] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5959.619357] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: The device has cellular connectivity and I'd say that the SD card would hold a bootable software to run the device. Is it identified at all when connected to a machine? Linux command `lsusb` and the kernel log (`dmesg`) will give you clues.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a USB GSM/UMTS modem. The kernel logs are compatible. It is (was?) used to connect to internet from a PC using a SIM.

This is one such product:
https://m.tomtop.com/it/p-c2070.html

The MicroSD is used to store user data, to use it as a memory stick, or sometimes used to provide management software for the modem

Here superuser question a regarding the MicroSD functionality
https://superuser.com/questions/781844/why-mobile-internet-sticks-have-a-microsd-slot

With the case il looks like this:

[image: Example USB dongle 1]
[image: Example USB dongle 2]